# 2d int Array sorting based on second column

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I have created a 2D array that I want to sort based on the second column. I have checked other variants however they doesn't seem to work.

At the moment data comes up as as first group and I want to get a second group.

```
0 0                 0 0
1 1065              6 24
2 70                3 60
3 60                2 70
4 90                4 90
5 251               5 251
6 24                7 558
7 558               1 1065
```

My code at the moment is:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Testing {

public static void test() {
    int[][] arrayToSort = {{0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, {0, 1065, 70, 60,90,251,24,558}};

}

public static void sortArray(int myArray[][]) {
    Arrays.sort(myArray, new Comparator<int[]>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
            return Integer.valueOf(o1[1]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o2[1]));
        }

    });
}
```

}

Comment: don't you want to sort all the columns?? the second example has your first column out of order because of the order of the second column...

Comment: what is your current output?

Comment: I need to sort only first column because these numbers are pairs. First column is index while second is distance. My current output is first group.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your method is sorting an outer array - which contains two elements only (which are arrays). Think of your problem as having two separate arrays: `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` and `{0,1065,70,60,90,251,24,558}`. Then your problem is to sort the second array, and have the identical swaps done in the first array. I would say that your data structure is generally not good for this task. Consider having a List of pairs instead:

```
public class Testing {

    private static class MyNumber {
        private final int id;
        private final int number;

        public MyNumber(int id, int number) {
            this.id = id;
            this.number = number;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getNumber() {
            return number;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] arrayToSort = {
                {0, 1,    2,  3,  4,  5,   6,  7  },
                {0, 1065, 70, 60, 90, 251, 24, 558}
        };

        List<MyNumber> list = IntStream.range(0, arrayToSort[0].length)
                .mapToObj(i -> new MyNumber(arrayToSort[0][i], arrayToSort[1][i]))
                .collect(toList());

        Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing(MyNumber::getNumber));

        for (MyNumber myNumber : list) {
            System.out.println(myNumber.getId() + " " + myNumber.getNumber());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use TreeMap to store 2nd row of the array as key and 1st row as the value.

Since the key , value are integer, you don't need to create any new Comparator/Comparable class to sort them. TreeMap will automatically store them in ascending order.

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
int[][] ax = {{0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7}, 
              {0, 1065, 70, 60,90,251,24,558} };

        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < ax[0].length; i++) {
            map.put(ax[1][i], ax[0][i] );
        }

    // Iterate over the TreeMap to get as per your wish order

       for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                                  + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }

    }
```